# Unable to run node server.js

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');

// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Set a response type of plain text for the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send back a response and end the connection
    res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 3000');
```

I am using the above code to create a simple server.

But when i am running it, I am getting error.

> Nileshs-MacBook-Pro:azureSocketServer njha$ node server.js
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/njha/Documents/AzureSample/azureSocketServer/server.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
>     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>     requireStack: []
>   }

My folder structure.
[image]

Comment: There is no error on my side, what version of node are you using ? Can we see more of the stacktrace ?

Comment: More description required

Comment: Please check now .. Node version (12.14.1)

Comment: wherer is your `server.js`? and from where you are running it?

Comment: It seems you are not in the same folder as your `server.js` file

Comment: server.js is my file name. And I am running it from this folder (azureSocketServer). I update my question with folder structure.

Comment: so you need to run `node src/server.js`

Comment: @NileshJha the code you posted is that all that's in the `server.js` file?

Comment: yes @MickaelB. is right. OR, you can set it in package.json and start using `node .`

Comment: Are you sure all of your packages have been installed? Run `npm install` prior to starting your server.

Comment: @Rastalamm it doesn't look like there are any packages being used in that code snippet

Comment: @MickaelB. Thanks... Its my mistake.. Now working fine..